# Class.forName() throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

A Thinking in Java program is as follows:

```
package typeinfo;
import static util.Print.*;

class Candy {
 static { print("Loading Candy"); }
}

class Gum {
 static { print("Loading Gum"); }
}

class Cookie {
 static { print("Loading Cookie"); }
}

public class SweetShop {
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
   print("inside main");
   new Candy();
   print("After creating Candy");
   try {
     Class.forName("Gum");
   } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
     print("Couldn't find Gum");
   }
   print("After Class.forName(\"Gum\")");
   new Cookie();
   print("After creating Cookie");
 }
}
```

I am expecting the output as follows:

```
/* Output:
inside main
Loading Candy
After creating Candy
Loading Gum
After Class.forName("Gum")
Loading Cookie
After creating Cookie
*/
```

But get

```
inside main
Loading Candy
After creating Candy
Couldn't find Gum
After Class.forName("Gum")
Loading Cookie
After creating Cookie
```

Obviously the try block is throwing a ClassNotFoundException, which is unexpected. Any ideas why the code throws this instead of initializing the Gum class, as expected?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your classes are in the package `typeinfo`, so their fully-qualified names are `typeinfo.Gum`, `typeinfo.Candy` and `typeinfo.Cookie`. [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) only accepts fully-qualified names:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `className` - the fully qualified name of the desired class.

Change your code to:

```
try {
  Class.forName("typeinfo.Gum");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
  print("Couldn't find Gum");
}
```

Comment: I like this, but to extend it further, is there a way to iterate through my program packages to try find it without the fqn?

Comment: @Enjoy87: Not in a portable way, as far as I know. (If you have a specific jar file or directory you can look in there, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: the reason is not explained in the book, that is strange.