# Using forName to retrieve a class in the test module via main

Tags: java, reflection, junit

In my main module, I have some code which uses forName(). In a JUnit test I've created a dummy class which I'm trying to retrieve from the main module.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static class DummyClass implements OtherClass { ... }

@Test
void testCase() {
    ParserHandler parserHandler = new ParserHandler();
    String fullClassName = DummyEntity.class.getCanonicalName();

    // fullClassName is used in the following method which uses forName()
    parserHandler.run(fullClassName);
}
```

Whenever I try this, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.x.y.TestClass.DummyEntity
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class.forName() throws ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417254/class-forname-throws-classnotfoundexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canonical Names are great for nice formatting, but that's not what you're looking for. You should use [`Class#getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) instead:

```
String fullClassName = DummyEntity.class.getName();
```